# getting an error when trying to enable versioning on multiple s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi guys each time I use this script to enable versioning on multiple S3 buckets I have an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated

aws s3 ls | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs -L 1 aws s3 put-bucket-versioning --versioning-configuration status=Enabled --bucket

Answer (score 0):

Use `s3api` instead of `s3`. Also, `status` should be `Status`:

```
aws s3 ls | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs -L 1 aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled --bucket
```

FYI, you can debug such situations by asking it to `echo` the command to screen instead of running it, eg:

```
aws s3 ls | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs -L 1 echo aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled --bucket
```